# What is the proper way to create div inside a div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-9

Seems [Angle Brackets Are Not Allowed in the createElement Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986077%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) has some impact on plugins.

I do not have the plugin, nor IE9 but for my own education, what is a proper way to code the following two lines in jQuery 1.6+

```
$('<div id="'+options.loupeWrap.substring(1)+'"><div id="'+options.loupe.substring(1)+'" /></div>').appendTo(options.appendTo);
$('<div id="'+options.zoomWrapper.substring(1)+'" />').appendTo(options.loupe);
```

for example I have seen
`$('<div class="bla"></div>')` but not `$('<div id="bla"></div>')` and am curious how to **cleanly** create a div with an ID and chain it to another div with an ID using the best practice jQuery possible and not just something that works because jQuery is very clever.

I also checked out [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

[This SEEMS to be valid and correct](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/BzeDe/)

Is it?

```
$('<div>')
  .attr('id',outerID)
  .append(
    $('<div>')
    .attr('id',innerID)
  )
  .appendTo(options.appendTo);
```

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I just tried CoolEsh's fiddle in IE9, it works fine. So if this characteristic happens to be unique to IE9 (which I do not know) then jQuery deals with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how I did it with jQuery:

```
$('<div>', { 
    id: 'outsidediv'
}).append( $('<div>', { 
    id: 'innerdiv'
})).appendTo('#container');
```

Example: [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SuperPhil/eASmj/) * The example shows how you can add html to the divs

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div id="myelement">My Element Content</div>
```

JS:

```
$( '<div id="outer">Outer Div Content<div id="inner">Inner Div Content</div></div>' ).appendTo( '#myelement' );
```

So what's the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/657nG/1/

Comment: This is part of jQuery's most basic behavior and its intended use. There's nothing unsafe about it (I mean, to the extent that you are passing valid markup and a unique ID).

Comment: The problem seems that it generates invalid (according to IE) markup where createElement gets html tags which are no longer allowed in IE9. I do not have IE9 so I cannot verify what works, but I think $('<div>') is ok and $('<div><div></div></div>') is not

Comment: Ok, can we make it more elegant and jQuery-like at least? Like $('div').attr('id','outer').append($('div').attr('id','inner')).appendTo(myelement) or something cleaner than what is there now?

Comment: I think $( '<div id="outer">Outer Div Content<div id="inner">Inner Div Content</div></div>' ).appendTo( '#myelement' ); is more readable than queue of attr's and appends.

Comment: But it embeds the angle brackets in the creation. The chained calls are more logical in my opinion. But it seems noone else have any suggestions.